# Can anyone identify the brand of this bathroom faucet? Looking to replace worn handles

Tags: bathroom, faucet, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

Bathroom faucet in Menlo Park, Ca. We're looking to replace the handles due to the yellow coloring/ wear on them but couldn't find any markings of identifying symbols for the brand, any help is appreciated.

[image: Shot 1]

[image: shot 2]

Comment: Look at the spout from underneath and behind very closely. Underneath you might be able to get a cell phone camera to focus - behind it's probably going to require a mirror, as there's not much space there.

Comment: Might also try using plain color paper or cardboard to remove all the reflecting surfaces, and all the background clutter, and some less angled pictures that way to improve the odds of a useful result in an image search.

Comment: Just a thought, might want to search youtube for Nickle electroplating. It's an easy DIY.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't identify the maker, you could presumably remove them and send them out for re-plating, since presumably the "yellow color" is wearing through the plating to brass underneath.

Comment: Or remove the plating and have brass fixture/s.

Answer (score 0):

This MIGHT be a Paul Decorative lavatory set. They did some sets that have similar square fittings that the handles fit on top of. I believe they are out of business, but their home page is still active here: https://www.pauldecorative.com/

You may be able to just buy handles from another manufacturer and see if they fit on the cartridges. Quite a few faucet handles use the same grooves, and it's more a matter of how high they sit off the base rather than whether they will turn the cartridge. In our case, we had Grohe fauctets/cartridges but didn't like the handles, and used the Paul handles and that square section they fit on.